# fixing old_version on yowsup

Tags: python, yowsup

I have been tring to register number on Yowsup, but I got `old_version` error.
Here is my `env_s40.py` file:

```
    from .env import YowsupEnv
import hashlib
class S40YowsupEnv(YowsupEnv):
    _VERSION = "2.16.11"
    _OS_NAME= "S40"
    _OS_VERSION = "14.26"
    _DEVICE_NAME = "302"
    _MANUFACTURER = "Nokia"
    _TOKEN_STRING  = "PdA2DJyKoUrwLw1Bg6EIhzh502dF9noR9uFCllGk1478194306452"
    _AXOLOTL = True

    def getVersion(self):
        return self.__class__._VERSION

    def getOSName(self):
        return self.__class__._OS_NAME

    def getOSVersion(self):
        return self.__class__._OS_VERSION

    def getDeviceName(self):
        return self.__class__._DEVICE_NAME

    def getManufacturer(self):
        return self.__class__._MANUFACTURER

    def isAxolotlEnabled(self):
        return self.__class__._AXOLOTL

    def getToken(self, phoneNumber):
        return hashlib.md5(self.__class__._TOKEN_STRING.format(phone = phoneNumber).encode()).hexdigest()

    def getUserAgent(self):
        return self.__class__._USERAGENT_STRING.format(
            WHATSAPP_VERSION = self.getVersion(),
            OS_NAME = self.getOSName() + "Version",
            OS_VERSION = self.getOSVersion(),
            DEVICE_NAME = self.getDeviceName(),
            MANUFACTURER = self.getManufacturer()
        )
```

And I got

```
DEBUG:yowsup.env.env:Current env changed to s40 
yowsup-cli  v2.0.15
yowsup      v2.5.0

Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Tarek Galal
http://www.openwhatsapp.org

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://openwhatsapp.org/yowsup/donate


DEBUG:yowsup.common.http.warequest:{'Accept': 'text/json', 'User-Agent': 'WhatsApp/2.16.7 S40Version/14.26 Device/Nokia-302'}
DEBUG:yowsup.common.http.warequest:cc=255&in=716343889&lc=GB&lg=en&sim_mcc=640&sim_mnc=002&mcc=640&mnc=002&method=sms&mistyped=6&network_radio_type=1&simnum=1&s=&copiedrc=1&hasinrc=1&rcmatch=1&pid=6444&rchash=5b9d791a39befe77a165a669cac86d3fa12c7390536885aa43555059748747e9&anhash=Q%90%1D%2Am%BA%EF%1C%8E%E1%84%94%E4%93%C6%DD%AB%B55E&extexist=1&extstate=1&token=fe234b378d154c6dcca365d264ed96cf&id=%A0%3B%2B%C3%B6%A2%F9%04%CB%FA%AE%887%7FY%F7E%E6%D3%17
DEBUG:yowsup.common.http.warequest:Opening connection to v.whatsapp.net
DEBUG:yowsup.common.http.warequest:Sending GET request to /v2/code?cc=255&in=716343889&lc=GB&lg=en&sim_mcc=640&sim_mnc=002&mcc=640&mnc=002&method=sms&mistyped=6&network_radio_type=1&simnum=1&s=&copiedrc=1&hasinrc=1&rcmatch=1&pid=6444&rchash=5b9d791a39befe77a165a669cac86d3fa12c7390536885aa43555059748747e9&anhash=Q%90%1D%2Am%BA%EF%1C%8E%E1%84%94%E4%93%C6%DD%AB%B55E&extexist=1&extstate=1&token=fe234b378d154c6dcca365d264ed96cf&id=%A0%3B%2B%C3%B6%A2%F9%04%CB%FA%AE%887%7FY%F7E%E6%D3%17
INFO:yowsup.common.http.warequest:{"login":"255716MYNUMBER","status":"fail","reason":"old_version"}

status: fail
reason: old_version
login: 255716MYNUMBER
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bad question for so.

But a short google gave:

https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/issues/1861#issuecomment-264792842

There are also other discussions regarding a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

in the `env_android` file change the version to the most current one (whatsapp):

[image]